# Strange behavior when killling text in term/multi-term

Tags: term, kill-text, multi-term

`multi-term` is my current goto when I want a command line in Emacs. However, I have noticed a strange behavior, and I am not sure whether it is a bug, or if it can be configured.

If I type a command at the prompt - or any text for that matter, and kill the text with `backward-kill-word` (`M-BACKSPACE` for me), the text no longer shows up, but behaves like it is still there (see the screenshot, and you will know what I mean). This is what happens when I type `ls`, kill the text with `backward-kill-word`, type `ls` again, and hit enter.

[image]

A similar, but slightly stranger thing happens when I move to the front of the text and use `kill-word`. Below is a the result of typing `ls`, moving to the beginning of the line, killing the text, and typing `ls` again (notice the cursor position too).

[image]

This certainly seems buggy, but I am not sure. This happens in `term` as well, which is to be expected, so the problem is likely with `term` and inherited by `multi-term`. If I just delete one character at a time, nothhing goes wrong (but who has time to delete one character at a time! I use Emacs so I don't have to do such things. I am not an animal!) Also, this only happens in `char mode`, not `line mode`, which leads me to believe that maybe it is an intentional feature that I just don't understand. The docs `term` include the following sentence:

> In char sub-mode, each character (except `term-escape-char') is sent immediately to the subprocess.

I don't actually understand what this means, but sound potentially related...Any ideas what is  going on? Thank you!

Comment: See that 'duplicate' answer for code which will prevent this from happening, but note that the fix is to *disable* killing (and yanking) commands in `term-char-mode`, because killing text in char mode puts the command line into an inconsistent state. In char mode you should only use the shell's bindings for movement and deletion. Also note that the purpose of line mode is to facilitate using Emacs' own editing commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. You can't use emacs commands in `term-char-mode`, you must toggle to `term-line-mode` for these commands...

But, you can use the terminal commands instead. For example C-w is the terminal `backward-kill-word`. fortunately, a lot of commands have (almost) the same behavior in terminal and in emacs (C-k, M-c, M-l, M-. ...).

Another problem is that multi-term (as term) intercept some commands so you must change the default configuration for using them.

Here the muti-term configuration I use: http://djangoliv.blogspot.fr/2015/10/emacs-term.html

important precisions:

- I am using two instances of emacs. One for the terminal (the conf above) and another (server) for the rest. It let me use terms in another frame but with emacs facilities.
- I use C-x (not C-c) as prefix in emacs term.
- I use tabbar and tabbar-more (http://djangoliv.blogspot.fr/2015/11/tabbar.html)

Hope this help.